# Is a Lie group $\sigma$-compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lie-groups, compactness

Is a Lie group $\sigma$-compact?
I want to use the Riesz representation theorem for show there is $\mu$ a bi-invariant Haar measure on a Lie group $L$  such that

$$I(f)=\int_L f d \mu$$

where $I$ is a linear functional on a Lie group $L$.

Comment: Give some sentences explaining what you have already done on this issue.

Comment: Well, I know every Lie group $L$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space but Riesz representation theorem needs $\sigma$-compact hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Of course, it all depends on your definitions - but it seems that *most* people require differential manifolds (and hence Lie groups) to be second countable. Since they are also locally compact, this means they are $\sigma$-compact.

However, one should be careful. The book *Structure and Geometry of Lie Groups* by J. Hilgert and K. Neeb doesn't require manifolds or Lie groups to be second countable, so for example $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology is considered a Lie group (and it's not $\sigma$-compact). But this is pretty nonconventional.

**EDIT:** It is also important to note that, as José pointed out, every *connected* Lie group is automatically $\sigma$-compact (and in fact second countable). I'll copy the proof from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1372343):

Suppose $G$ is a connected Lie Group. Let $K$ be any compact neighbourhood of the identity. Then the interior $\text{int}(K)$ is an open neighbourhood of the identity as well. Take $V = \text{int}(K) \cap \text{int}(K)^{-1}$; $V$ is still an open neighbourhood of the identity and $V \subset K$.

Consider $H = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}V^n$. This is an open subgroup of $G$. Therefore it is closed, since its complement $H^C = \bigcup_{g \neq e \in G} gH$ is open. Because $G$ is connected and $H$ is nonempty, $H = G$. In particular,

$$ G = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}V^n = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}K^n.$$

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that you are interested only in *connected* Lie groups. Then, yes, it is $\sigma$-compact. In fact, if $U$ is a compact neighborhood of the identity element, then $\{U^n\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a countable collection of compact sets whose union is the whole group.